# Symfony2 interacting with existing session

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am trying to read and write from a session started by a `PHP`'s native session. I have found information about it but I actually cannot interact with this session. I used this two documents:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/php_bridge.html

If I understand it well, I should be able to get the attributes of this session once the `PhpBridgeSessionStorage` has been started? If so, I only get an empty array.

> Here is how I coded it:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {  

//I get my service, execute and then the session is created.
      $phpCas = $this->container->get('phpcas');
      $phpCas->execute();

// I start a new Session and display what's inside
      $session = new Session();
      $session->start();
      $array = $session->all();
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($array);
      echo "</pre>";
      return;
```

> In my service I start a php bridge session like this:

```
    public function execute()
        {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/source/config.php';

            ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
            ini_set('session.save_path', '/tmp');
            session_start();

            phpCAS::setDebug();
            phpCAS::client(SAML_VERSION_1_1, $cas_host, $cas_port, $cas_context);
            phpCAS::setCasServerCACert($cas_server_ca_cert_path);
            phpCAS::handleLogoutRequests(true, $cas_real_hosts);

//In forceAuthentication(), this is going to 
start again a session and create a cookie.

        phpCAS::forceAuthentication();

    //I start a new phpBridgeSessionStorage to interact with this session
                $session = new Session(new PhpBridgeSessionStorage());
                $session->start();
            }
```

> In my app/config.yml I have written this:

```
session: 
        storage_id: session.storage.php_bridge
        handler_id: ~
        save_path: null
```

I am using `Linux`, could it be a problem of permission to read/write into `/tmp`? Or is it me who don't understand the documentation and didn't write my code correctly to make it interacting?

Thank you for your help